# SPARQL not showing a part of results with Image grid view

Tags: sparql, rdf, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I created a query to find female artists based on some conditions, and wanted to include pictures to the result of the query so that #defaultView: ImageGrid view shows not only the required data, but also a corresponding image of the artist(P18). I understand that sometimes the image may be absent, so I used an OPTIONAL clause not to lose the data about artists without an image.

However, when default view is set to ImageGrid, I don't get to see all the results. To check all of them I have to switch to Table View.

The query is:

```
#defaultView:ImageGrid

SELECT distinct
  (year(?birthDate) as ?year)
  ?person
  ?personLabel
  (count(distinct ?notablework) as ?workCount)
  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?notableworkLabel; separator="; ") AS ?works )
  (sample(?image) as ?imageSample)
  ?placeOfBirth
  ?cood

WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P106 wd:Q483501 .
  ?person rdfs:label ?personLabel .
  FILTER (LANG ( ?personLabel ) = "en" )
  
  ?person wdt:P21 wd:Q6581072 .
  ?person wdt:P569 ?birthDate .
  
  ?person wdt:P800 ?notablework .
  ?notablework rdfs:label ?notableworkLabel .
  FILTER (LANG ( ?notableworkLabel ) = "en" )
  
  FILTER(year(?birthDate) > 1899 && year(?birthDate) < 2000)
  
  ?person wdt:P27 wd:Q30 .
  ?person wdt:P6379 wd:Q160236.
  
  OPTIONAL {?person wdt:P18 ?image} .
  OPTIONAL {?person wdt:P19 ?country .
    ?country rdfs:label ?placeOfBirth .
    ?country wdt:P625 ?cood .
    FILTER (LANG ( ?placeOfBirth ) = "en")
  }
}

GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?placeOfBirth ?cood ?birthDate
HAVING (?workCount >= 3)
ORDER BY ?personLabel
```

and an OPTIONAL clause I'm talking about is line 30:
`OPTIONAL {?person wdt:P18 ?image} .`

[Query actually retrieves 7 results,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4rRS.png)
[But only 3 are shown in an image grid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCRYz.png)

Using an OPTIONAL clause, I expected to see all of the 7 results in ImageGrid view, thinking there would be some kind of 'Image is not available' message put instead of the picture, but that didn't happen.

I also thought it has something to do with my browser, but switching from Firefox to Chrome didn't work out.

Is there actually a way to do something like that in SPARQL or the expected layout I described is not generally implemented into the service?

Comment: a workaround is to render any other place holder image if there is no such image in the data: `OPTIONAL {?person wdt:P18 ?image_} .
  BIND(COALESCE(?image_, <http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/File:Profile_avatar_placeholder_large.png>) AS ?image)`

Answer (score 1):

As said by UninformedUser in the comments, you can use the following SPARQL snippet:

```
OPTIONAL {?person wdt:P18 ?image_} .
BIND(
    COALESCE(?image_, <http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/File:Profile_avatar_placeholder_large.png>)
    AS ?image)
```

According to the [SPARQL 1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce):

> The COALESCE function form returns the RDF term value of the first expression that evaluates without error.

So if the `?image_` variable is matched in the OPTIONAL clause, it will be bind to the `?image` variable. Otherwise a default image will be bind to the `?image` variable.